# How implement Search in ActiveScaffold Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, activescaffold

My Normal search in the activescaffold list page is not working.

I have ListLocations table which has fields  id | list_id | wiki_location_id. 
I have following model relations

```
       class List < ActiveRecord::Base
         validates_presence_of :name
         has_many :list_locations, :dependent => :destroy
       end


       class WikiLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
         has_many :list_locations, :dependent => :destroy
       end

       class ListLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
         belongs_to :list
         belongs_to :wiki_location

         def wiki_location_title
           WikiLocation.find(wiki_location_id).title if wiki_location_id
         end

         def wiki_location_title= (title)
           wiki_location = WikiLocation.find_by_title(title)
           self.wiki_location_id = wiki_location.id if wiki_location
         end
       end
```

My Controller for these are

```
      class Admin::ListsController < Admin::AdminController
        active_scaffold :list do |conf|
          conf.columns = [:name, :list_order, :enabled]
          conf.columns[:enabled].form_ui = :checkbox 
          conf.columns[:enabled].inplace_edit = true
          list.sorting = {:list_order => 'asc'}
        end
      end


      class Admin::WikiLocationsController < Admin::AdminController
        active_scaffold :wiki_location do |conf|
          conf.columns = [:title, :street]
          list.per_page = 10
        end
      end 


     class Admin::ListLocationsController < Admin::AdminController  
       active_scaffold :list_location do |conf|
         conf.columns = [:list, :wiki_location]
         conf.columns[:list].form_ui = :select
         conf.search.columns << :list
       end
     end
```

I also have implemented Search as you type(SAYT) feature for wiki_location field in List_Locations table

My views look like

[image]

[image]

I have implemented the auto-complete feature by following the instructions in the below specified link  [Activescaffold autocomplete](http://compdocjos.blogspot.in/2010/11/creating-autocompleting-association.html)

Now my issue is when I use the normal search in my list page of active scaffold I am not getting any results

The query that I got from my console is

```
 SELECT `list_locations`.`id` AS t0_r0, `list_locations`.`list_id` AS t0_r1, 
 `list_locations`.`wiki_location_id` AS t0_r2, `list_locations`.`created_at` AS t0_r3,
 `list_locations`.`updated_at` AS t0_r4, `lists`.`id` AS t1_r0, `lists`.`name` AS t1_r1,
 `lists`.`list_order` AS t1_r2, `lists`.`enabled` AS t1_r3, `lists`.`created_at` AS 
  t1_r4, `lists`.`updated_at` AS t1_r5 FROM `list_locations` LEFT OUTER JOIN `lists` ON 
 `lists`.`id` = `list_locations`.`list_id` WHERE ((((`lists`.`id` LIKE '%museum%'))))
  ORDER BY `list_locations`.`id` ASC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0
```

It looks like its searching on lists.id field instead of list.name

Why is it like this. How can I make it search list.name. I also need to search wiki_locations.title  column too. How can this be done. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set:

```
conf.columns[:list].search_sql = 'list.name'
```